# using DataSet.repartition in Spark 2 - several tasks handle more than one partition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

we have a spark streaming application (spark 2.1 run over Hortonworks 2.6) and use the `DataSet.repartition` (on a `DataSet<Row>` that's read from Kafka) in order to repartition the `DataSet<Row>'s` partitions according to a given column (called *block_id*).

We start with a `DataSet<Row>`containing 50 partitions and end up (after the call to `DataSet.repartition`) with number of partitions equivalent to the number of unique *block_id's*.

The problem is that the `DataSet.repartition` behaves not as we expected - when we look at the event timeline of the spark job that runs the `repartition`, we see there are several tasks that handle 1 *block_id* and fewer tasks that handle 2 *block_id's* or even 3 or 4 *block_id's*.

It seems that `DataSet.repartition` ensures that all the `Rows` with the same *block_id* will be inside a single partition, but not that each task that creates a partition will handle only one block_id.

The result is that the repartition job (that runs inside the streaming application) takes as much time as its longest task (which is the task that handles the most *block_id's*.

We tried playing with the number of Vcores given to the streaming app  - from 10 to 25 to 50 (we have 50 partitions in the original RDD that's read from Kafka) but the result was the same - there's always one or more task that handles more than one *block_id*.

We even tried increasing the batch time, again that didn't help us to achieve the goal of one task handling one *block_id*.

To give an example - here's the event timeline and the tasks table describing a run of the `repartition`spark job:

**event timeline** - the two tasks in red are the ones that handle two *block_id's*:

[image]

**tasks table** - the two tasks in red are the same two from above - notice the duration of each of them is twice as the duration of all other tasks (that handle only one *block_id*)

[image]

This is a problem for us because the streaming application is delayed due to these long tasks and we need a solution that will enable us to perform `repartition` on a DataSet while having each task handling only one *block_id*.

And if that's not possible then maybe that's possible on an `JavaRDD?` Since in our case the `DataSet<Row>` we run the `repartition` on is created from a `JavaRDD`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 problems you need to consider:

- Have a custom partitioner that assures data uniform distribution, 1 block_id / partition
- Sizing the cluster so that you have enough executors to run all tasks (block_ids) simultaneously

As you've seen a simple repartition on the DataFrame doesn't assure you'll get an uniform distribution. When you repartition by block_id it will use the HashPartitioner, with formula:

```
Utils.nonNegativeMod(key.hashCode, numPartitions)
```

See: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L80-L88

It's very possible 2+ keys are assigned to the same partition_id as the partition_id is key's hashCode modulo numPartitions.

What you need can be achieved by using the RDD with a custom partitioner. The easiest will be to extract the list of distinct block_ids before repartitioning.

Here's a simple example. Let's say you can have 5 blocks (2,3,6,8,9) and your cluster has 8 executors (can run up to 8 tasks simultaneously), we're over-provisioned by 3 executors:

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
res0: String = 8

scala> spark.conf.get("spark.default.parallelism")
res1: String = 8

// Basic class to store dummy records
scala> case class MyRec(block_id: Int, other: String)
defined class MyRec

// Sample DS
scala> val ds = List((2,"A"), (3,"X"), (3, "B"), (9, "Y"), (6, "C"), (9, "M"), (6, "Q"), (2, "K"), (2, "O"), (6, "W"), (2, "T"), (8, "T")).toDF("block_id", "other").as[MyRec]
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyRec] = [block_id: int, other: string]

scala> ds.show
+--------+-----+
|block_id|other|
+--------+-----+
|       2|    A|
|       3|    X|
|       3|    B|
|       9|    Y|
|       6|    C|
|       9|    M|
|       6|    Q|
|       2|    K|
|       2|    O|
|       6|    W|
|       2|    T|
|       8|    T|
+--------+-----+

// Default partitioning gets data distributed as uniformly as possible (record count)
scala> ds.rdd.getNumPartitions
res3: Int = 8

// Print records distribution by partition
scala> ds.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, it) => Iterator((idx, it.toList))).toDF("partition_id", "block_ids").show
+------------+--------------+
|partition_id|     block_ids|
+------------+--------------+
|           0|       [[2,A]]|
|           1|[[3,X], [3,B]]|
|           2|       [[9,Y]]|
|           3|[[6,C], [9,M]]|
|           4|       [[6,Q]]|
|           5|[[2,K], [2,O]]|
|           6|       [[6,W]]|
|           7|[[2,T], [8,T]]|
+------------+--------------+

// repartitioning by block_id leaves 4 partitions empty and assigns 2 block_ids (6,9) to same partition (1)
scala> ds.repartition('block_id).rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, it) => Iterator((idx, it.toList))).toDF("partition_id", "block_ids").where(size('block_ids) > 0).show(false)
+------------+-----------------------------------+
|partition_id|block_ids                          |
+------------+-----------------------------------+
|1           |[[9,Y], [6,C], [9,M], [6,Q], [6,W]]|
|3           |[[3,X], [3,B]]                     |
|6           |[[2,A], [2,K], [2,O], [2,T]]       |
|7           |[[8,T]]                            |
+------------+-----------------------------------+

// Create a simple mapping for block_id to partition_id to be used by our custom partitioner (logic may be more elaborate or static if the list of block_ids is static):
scala> val mappings = ds.map(_.block_id).dropDuplicates.collect.zipWithIndex.toMap
mappings: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(6 -> 1, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 8 -> 4)

//custom partitioner assigns partition_id according to the mapping arg
scala> class CustomPartitioner(mappings: Map[Int,Int]) extends org.apache.spark.Partitioner {
     |   override def numPartitions: Int = mappings.size
     |   override def getPartition(rec: Any): Int = { mappings.getOrElse(rec.asInstanceOf[Int], 0) }
     | }
defined class CustomPartitioner

// Repartition DS using new partitioner
scala> val newDS = ds.rdd.map(r => (r.block_id, r)).partitionBy(new CustomPartitioner(mappings)).toDS
newDS: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, MyRec)] = [_1: int, _2: struct<block_id: int, other: string>]

// Display evenly distributed block_ids
scala> newDS.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, it) => Iterator((idx, it.toList))).toDF("partition_id", "block_ids").where(size('block_ids) > 0).show(false)
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|partition_id|block_ids                                   |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|0           |[[9,[9,Y]], [9,[9,M]]]                      |
|1           |[[6,[6,C]], [6,[6,Q]], [6,[6,W]]]           |
|2           |[[3,[3,X]], [3,[3,B]]]                      |
|3           |[[2,[2,A]], [2,[2,K]], [2,[2,O]], [2,[2,T]]]|
|4           |[[8,[8,T]]]                                 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: we tried your approach (translated the scala code you wrote to java) and most of the times it works (which means that all tasks inside the RDD.repartition job are linear - each handles an equal amount of partitions). However there are times when one of the tasks inside the RDD.repartition job gets stuck forever, I guess on an infinite loop (since the top shows exactly 100%). This causes the streaming to get stuck and only restart helps in that case. Is it a known bug in spark2?

Comment: is there a chance a partition (block) becomes too large (a large key causing data skew, causing GC)? can you try logging a top 10 counts of records per block, maybe running verbose gc and digging deeper when that happens, checking thread dumps for running tasks, etc. (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html). This approach relies on the data being properly balanced otherwise a block with 1 row vs one with 1M rows will still cause processing skew even if each executor processes just 1.

Comment: every time the RDD.repartition job stucks the streaming app, it's caused by some tasks that are stuck. every time this bug occurs, these tasks are the only ones that handle less(!!) records than all the other tasks. e.g. - if the repartition job has 50 tasks, then 46 tasks handle exactly 1M records and the 4 stuck ones handle less than that. so we can identify that this bug is always caused by tasks that handle less than the required amount of rows. we verified GC isn't the problem, and the thread dump only shows 4 threads in WAITING status.

Comment: @EladEldor did you find the root cause and a solution? Thanks.